# jQuery - анимация одного блока при нажатии на другой

Tags: jquery, анимация

Есть такая конструкция:

HTML:

```
<div class="icon"><section class="four"><a href="#" class="hmbrgr four"></a></section></div>
```

Скрипт:

```
$(function() {
$('.hmbrgr.four').hmbrgr({
    width     : 30,
    height    : 22,
    barHeight : 3,
    barRadius : 3,
    barColor  : '#2a2a2a'
});
});

(function ( $ ) {

  $.fn.hmbrgr = function( settings ){

    var config = $.extend( {
      width     : 30,
      height    : 22,
      speed     : 200,
      barHeight : 3,
      barRadius : 0,
      barColor  : '#ffffff',
      animation : 'expand',
      onInit    : null,
      onOpen    : null,
      onClose   : null
    }, settings);

    var posTop    = 0,
        posMiddle = (config.height/2) - (config.barHeight/2),
        posBottom = config.height - config.barHeight;

    function hmbrgrBuild(el){
      $(el)
      .css({
        'width'     : config.width,
        'height'    : config.height
      })
      .html('<span /><span /><span />')
      .find('span').css({
        'position'            : 'absolute',
        'width'               : '100%',
        'height'              : config.barHeight,
        'border-radius'       : config.barRadius,
        'background-color'    : config.barColor,
        'transition-duration' : config.speed+'ms'
      });

      hmbrgrSpanReset(el);
      $.isFunction(config.onInit) && config.onInit.call(this);
    }

    function hmbrgrSpanReset(el){
      $(el)
      .data('clickable', true)
      .find('span').eq(0).css({
        'top' : posTop
      });

      $(el)
      .find('span').eq(1).css({
        'top' : posMiddle
      });

      $(el)
      .find('span').eq(2).css({
        'top' : posBottom
      });
    }

    function hmbrgrCommand(el){
      $(el).on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        if($(this).data('clickable')){

          $(this).data('clickable', false);

          $(el).toggleClass('cross');

          if( $(el).hasClass('cross') )
            hmbrgrExpand(el);
          else
            hmbrgrCollapse(el);
        }
      });
    }

    function hmbrgrExpand(el){
      $(el).find('span').css({
        top : posMiddle
      });

      setTimeout(function(){
        $(el).addClass(config.animation).data('clickable', true);
        $.isFunction(config.onOpen) && config.onOpen.call(this);
      }, config.speed);
    }

    function hmbrgrCollapse(el){
      $(el).removeClass(config.animation);

      setTimeout(function(){
        hmbrgrSpanReset(el);
        $.isFunction(config.onClose) && config.onClose.call(this);
      }, config.speed);
    }

    return this.each(function(){
      hmbrgrBuild(this);
      hmbrgrCommand(this);
    });

  };

}( jQuery ));
```

Скрипт - это иконка меню (три полоски), при нажатии на которую происходит анимация, и она становится крестиком. При повторном нажатии она снова преобразуется в три полоски, т.е. возвращается в исходное положение. Блок `div` с классом `icon` шириной 100%.

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии не только на иконку, но и на сам блок с классом `icon`, происходила анимация иконки?

Сейчас анимация иконки происходит непосредственно при нажатии на саму иконку.

css:

```
.icon {
    height: 42px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
}
.hmbrgr {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.hmbrgr span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
}
.hmbrgr.expand span:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.hmbrgr.expand span:nth-child(2) {
  zoom: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-opacity: 0;
  -moz-opacity: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
.hmbrgr.expand span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Comment: крестика не увидел - все три полоски сворачиваются в одну.

Comment: Потому что здесь отсутствуют стили css. Но они не важны и не нужны в решении данного вопроса.

Comment: ок. у вас hmbrgr - это плагин, расширяющий конкретный элемент `a.hmbrgr.four`. Вы можете применить его непосредственно к блоку icon:
`$('div.icon').hmbrgr({настройки});`

Единственно - надо что-то с шириной делать.

Comment: В таком случае нарушается вся конструкция, а иконка становится размером блока icon 100%. Такой вариант, к сожалению, не вариант.

Comment: Ну тогда вам надо ваш код из плагина преобразовать во что-то иное - некий объект, который может визуально модифицировать элементы, которые ему передаются в качестве параметра и поставлять функции-обработчики событий для произвольных элементов.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант костыля - эмулировать клик по иконке при клике по родителю. Нечто вроде

```
$('.icon').on('click', function(){
    $('.hmbrgr.four', this).click();
});
```

Comment: Прошу прощения за глупый вопрос, не совсем понял. Это отдельной строкой нужно вставить, или заменить какие-то строки?

Comment: Отдельной строкой, после вызова вашего плагина, т.е. после

$('.hmbrgr.four').hmbrgr({
    width     : 30,
    height    : 22,
    barHeight : 3,
    barRadius : 3,
    barColor  : '#2a2a2a'
});

Comment: Да, это вариант, так работает. Но в таком случае возникает один минус - анимация происходит с задержкой, где-то в пару секунд. Как этого можно избежать?

Comment: Единственное, что приходит в голову - оптимизировать ресурсы сайта. Поужимать картинки (например, здесь http://compresspng.com/), поужимать скрипты (http://jscompress.com/), поужимать СSS (http://csscompressor.com/).

Comment: Здесь, в этом случае, ресурсы вообще минимальные. Скриптом практически нет, только несколько строк, картинок также, и файл стиля минимальный. Задержка получается именно при таком варианте. Возможен ли какой-то другой вариант? Вы, я так понимаю, очень хорошо знаете jQuery, вот и хочу у вас, как у специалиста, спросить, есть ли еще какие иные варианты?

Comment: Можно немного кастомизировать ваш плагин. Проверить не могу, пока вы СSS не выложите. Можно попробовать заменить функцию function hmbrgrCommand(el) на такую:

function hmbrgrCommand(el){
      $(el).parents('.icon').on('click', function(e){
        $(el).preventDefault();

        if($(el).data('clickable')){

          $(el).data('clickable', false);

          $(el).toggleClass('cross');

          if( $(el).hasClass('cross') )
            hmbrgrExpand(el);
          else
            hmbrgrCollapse(el);
        }
      });
    }

Comment: Сергей, я добавил css. Будьте добры, посмотрите, пожалуйста. Очень хочется сделать все правильно.